# soffice.exe to Convert odt to PDF/A

Tags: pdf-generation, libreoffice, openoffice.org, pdfa

trying to convert ODT to PDF using soffice.exe, but it always give me only PDF and not PDF/A... 
Is there a way to convert odt to **PDF/A** using soffice.exe ?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that whatever format you successfully used last, to export a document as a Pdf, will be the default. So export something as a Pdf/A and then try again from the command line.
I have tried the `unoconv` option:

```
unoconv -f pdf -eFormsType=1 -eSelectedPdfVersion=1 Some.odt
```

and whilst it purports to work, the result give errors when tested as a Pdf/A file.

Whereas, the same file run through the:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf Some.odt
```

command does pass the test but only if the previous `export` was successfully made to a Pdf/A file.

Testing was performed using `pdfa` from http://www.pdftron.com/pdfamanager/downloads.html